# colcon package ignore regex

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I would like ignore `connext` and `cyclonedds` related packages e.g: `rmw_connextdds, rmw_connextdds_common, rti_connext_dds_cmake_module && cyclonedds, rmw_cyclonedds_cpp`

```
colcon build  --symlink-install --packages-ignore-regex connext cyclonedds
```

But I have a warning says

[0.349s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_core.package_discovery:the --packages-ignore-regex 'connext' doesn't match any of the package names.

How to have a proper regex to ignore the packages ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400019/colcon-package-ignore-regex/) by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2022-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The regex selection and skip arguments are implemented using python's [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match) meaning that the regular expression must patch the start of the string (in this case the package name) so changing the command to:

```
colcon build  --symlink-install --packages-ignore-regex '.*connext' '.*cyclonedds'
```

should have the intended effect.

---

Originally posted by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) with karma: 906 on 2022-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2